# How can I include a value in a circular way in order to do iterative calculations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one column that sums a series of numbers.

I have another column that takes the sum of the numbers * .25

I want to include the result of this second column in the first and have it run until the cell where the 4 is on the left is equal to the cell with the 4 on the right.  How do I do this to get around the circular reference?  I don't have a clue, so any point in the right direction on Excel's capabilities would help.

Iterations: say i have this example, where quarter == quarter of total

```
           1        
           1        
          10      quarter of total
quarter    4                     4
sum       16
```

But then the numbers change, and now my sum is 20

```
           1        
           5        
          10      quarter of total
quarter    4                     5
sum       20
```

Quarter of total updates, because it's just 20*.25.  But now the quarter cell is not equal to the quarter of total cell.  If I change the quarter cell to equal the quarter of total cell, the following happens:

```
           1        
           5        
          10      quarter of total
quarter    5                  5.25
sum       21
```

These are still not equal.  I need it to solve so that these two are equal.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Can you show us the first few iterations?

Comment: You will need to use the solver add in or write vba.  Circular referenced formula never work reliably.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the add in or vba.  I added iterations above.

Comment: Why iterate? The fourth line should always be equal to the average of the first 3.